# Is it possible to connect an external device to iPhone through USB

Tags: ios, iphone, usb

I have an external device for which firmware update has to be done through **iPhone**. The primary approach will be to transfer the file through BLE and from where, the external device will run the firmware update for itself. But as a fallback approach, i need the data transfer to be done via USB. The external device has an USB-C connector. So we can connect the external device through USB-C to lightning connector right? Will that work? And whether the data transfer is possible through that USB-C cable?.

Comment: That's not that easy. Is the external device produced by you? Then you could think of participating in the MFi program (Made for iPhone)

Comment: If you are jailbroken then yes for sure.. if not, then you need Apple's MFi program which is not cheap and under NDA..